# Embed an aspx page with in another aspx page's div section

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have to embed one aspx page in another aspx page's DIV section.
I have to show one aspx page within another aspx page's  section

Please help me for this

Comment: https://www.google.com/?q=iframe#q=iframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try using an IFrame?

```
<iframe src="secondpage.aspx"></iframe>
```

Other solution is using JQuery

```
$.get( "secondpage.aspx", function( data ) {
  $( "#result" ).html( data ); //get secondpage.aspx into #result
});

<div id="result"></div>
```